# How to modify (i.e. change part of, but keep the rest of JSON the same) a property in an array of objects using jq

Tags: json, jq

Note, I only want to change part of the JSON data in a large JSON blob.  Deep inside the JSON blob, there is an array of objects.  These objects have different properties, but I can identify the object I want to change by it's title.  I'd like to use `jq` to do this.

Here's an example JSON:

```
{
    "propA" : "valA",
    "anArrayOfObjs" : [
        {
            "title" : "blah",
            "objA" : {
                "objB" : {
                    "propA" : "valA",
                    "propB" : "valB"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "title" : "welcome",
            "objA" : {
                "objB" : {
                    "propA" : "valA",
                    "propC" : "valC"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "objA" : {
                "objB" : {
                    "propA" : "valA",
                    "propD" : "valD"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to change the value of `objA.objB.propA` only for the object in `anArrayOfObjs` where `title == "welcome"`.

thanks for any tips you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.path.to.anArrayOfObjs |= map(
  select(.title == "welcome").objA.objB.propA = "new value"
)
```

To modify multiple properties:

```
.path.to.anArrayOfObjs |= map(
  select(.title == "welcome").objA.objB |= (
    .propA = "new value" | .propC = "new value"
  )
)
```

Comment: thanks. that works.  What if I want to change many properties in the object with .title == "welcome"?  I think I set it to a $var.  and then I can use $var many times in the map() function?

Comment: I tried 
```
path.to.anArrayOfObjs |= map(select(.title == "welcome") as $item | $item.objA.objB.propA = "new value")
```
but that removed all the other objects from anArrayOfObjs

Comment: never mind.. answered my question above.  Didn't need to use a variable.